How to use Geocoder Autocomplete API of the new HERE Platform?
I'm currently having a confusion about why hitting this endpoint :
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apiKey={API_KEY}
results in a 403 http status code. And I'm sure the API key is not expired still.
I have a JS/jQuery codebase that send an ajax request to this endpoint to grab some data from it but when i test it manually in browser, like above, it doesn't work.
Any Help is appreciated.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. If the API is giving a 403 - Forbidden, really seems like the API Key is incorrect, expired, or not getting passed properly.

@Twisty no the api key has been regenerated yesterday and it does work for other endpoints such : https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=240+Washington+St.%2C+Boston&limit=4&apiKey={API-KEY}
now I just want to know if the endpoint returning 403 is still usable or it has been deprecated since HERE migrated to a new platform ?

Check which subscription plan are you in? That might be causing the issue
